# Type.InvokeMember with nullable parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

#### Project

I've developed a remoting class which is used to replace a subset of WCF. This has been done because we are targeting a mobile Plattform with Unity3D and need to keep the Memory consumption as small as possible. ( *So we don't need to include System.ServiceModel which actually has a size of 2.7MB which is a lot for a small mobile RAM* )

It's working fine right now for all types ( including complex types which will be serialized using my own serializer written years ago )  and it's also capable to handle complex situations ( A calls B, B calls A, A returns something, B returns something ).

#### Method invokation

For invoking methods on the target site i'm using `Type.InvokeMember` which actually works for the most cases except for nullable-types. And this is the problem i've faced. In my interface definition the method looks like this:

```
public interface IServerContract 
{
    void SetUsageID(Int32? id);
}
```

The `ServerProxy` ( A object which handles the call to the remote method ) i'm doing the following:

```
public class ServerProxy : ProxyBase
{
    public void SetUsageID(Int32? id)
    {
         RemoteCall("SetUsageID", id);
    }
}
```

As usual the parameter `id` is boxed because the definition of `RemoteCall` looks like this:

```
public void RemoteCall(String methodName, params Object[] arguments) { ... }
```

At this point i got only a `System.Int32` and not a nullable anymore. I'm serializing the arguments and deserializing them on the target machine. At this point i'm calling `Type.InvokeMethod` which causes a exception because he can't find a method which takes a `Int32` as first parameter ( second when not ignoring this ).

What is the best solution for this issue? There are serval ways but all would cause a performance impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxing rules for `int?` indeed mean that once you have it as an `object` you see:

- *empty* values are `null`, and nothing more can be discerned
- *non-empty* values are known only as the non-nullable type

  - so specifically, passing `(int)5` and `(int?)5` have **exactly** the same appearance within `object`

As such, the options available:

- ensure method names are unique, so you can uniquely resolve by name to a `MethodInfo`, then use `MethodInfo.Invoke` (this ensures no ambiguity in the parameters)
- try to resolve a method accepting the non-nullable type(s), then look for nullable type(s) instead (gets complex for multi-parameter methods)
- pass more metadata about what method you are calling (increases size)

Personally, though, I have a very simplistic view on such things... rather than trying to encode a vague multi-parameter method, another option is to simplify to always passing a **single**, DTO-based, parameter - i.e. instead of `SetUsageID(int?)` you could have `SetUsage(SetUsageArgs)` (or something similar), where `SetUsageArgs` happens to have a single property. The point being: you're now just encoding a single DTO, and once you have deserialized that DTO there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm creating unique id's for each of the methods when the connection is established and save them in a table, then i just have to send a 7bit encoded int over the network to find the correct method.